Weighted $L$ infinity norm and $L_w^\infty=L^\infty$
I have a doubt about the weighted $L$ infinity norm.
Context:
Definition: Let w a positive, locally integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $1<p<\infty$. Then w belongs to the Muckenhoupt class $A_p$ is there exists a constant $0<A<\infty$ such that  for all ball $B$,
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{|B|}\int_Bw(x)\,dx\right)^{1/p}\left(\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B {w(x)}^{-p'/p}\,dx\right)^{1/p'}\leq A
\end{align}
where $p'$ is given by $1/p+1/p'=1$, as usual.
Definition: The weighted Lebesgue space $L_w^p$ contains all measurable functions such that $\left\|f\right\|_{L_w^p}=\left\|w^{1/p}f\right\|_{L^p}$ is finite. Note that for $p=\infty$, $L_w^{\infty}=L^{\infty}$ for any $w$ Muckenhoupt weight.
Reference: D.D. Haroske, “Singularities in Muckenhoupt weighted function spaces,” in Function Spaces VIII, (Institute of Mathematics Polish Academy of Sciences, Będlewo, Poland, 2007), pp. 95–112.
Question 1: Is the weighted $L$ infinity norm defined as $\left\|f\right\|_{L_w^{\infty}}=\left\|wf\right\|_{L^\infty}$?
Question 2: Why $L_w^{\infty}=L^{\infty}$? I don't see this.
My attempt: $w$ positive implies that $C\leq w$ for some constant $C>0$. Then $\left\|f\right\|_{L^\infty}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|\frac{1}{w(x)}(w(x)f(x))|\leq \frac{1}{C}\left\|wf\right\|_{L^{\infty}}$. Therefore, $L^{\infty}\subset L_w^{\infty}$?. On other hand, the inclusion $L^\infty\subset L_w^\infty$ is not so obvious for me.
Thanks.

It's just a convention. $w^{1/\infty} = w^0=1$.

Oh! I see. Thanks.

But, in  R.C. Brown, and B. Opic, “Embeddings of Weighted Sobolev Spaces into Spaces of Continuous Functions,” Proceedings: Mathematical and Physical Sciences 439(1906), 279–296 (1992), the weighted $L$ infinity norm is defined by $\left|u\right|{\infty, \Omega,w}=\text{ess sup}{x\in \Omega}|u(x)w(x)|$ (equation (2.1))...I am confused.

Yes. Different sources define it differently. You need to check the specific source you are working with. The two basic ways are either defining the norm as $|wf|{L^p}$, or by incorporating the weight into the measure instead, which is equivalent to considering $|w^{1/p}f|{L^p}$.
